# Monitoring tool for thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program, running multiple thread, which suppose to run on server without stopping. I want a tool which will notify me if a thread has stopped, and also provide some information about each thread, so I can control my threads correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  Can you show us some code?  WHat have you tried?  Right now it is a candidate for closure because your question does not show these details.

Comment: this is no question. show us what you've tried yet and describe your problem.

Comment: Here is the thing, I run a multiple thread who caught via ports, a package of informations from a gps, every 5s, and what i need, it's to know by notification or something, if my thread has stops, so i can rerun my thread

Comment: Are you extending or implementing thread in java? Are those threads run from a main? or one thread creates a new thread? Please post a stub of what you are doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without paying lots of cash for a J2EE container that can do this for you (e.g. Websphere) the basic option is to have your Java threads write a "heartbeat" message to a log file every N seconds, and then have a process monitor the log file and send an alert if the heartbeat stops occurring.

Something like [Apache Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class will do for this purpose.

You can also think about creating a process that performs a *NIX "ps -ef" command on the host to ensure the process itself is running as another way to monitor

Answer (score 0):

Try to log with `log4j`. You might email error level logs via log4j by using a mail appender. Check this link [log4j appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: A good answer, however, one caveat is if the thread or process dies and doesn't log anything to Log4J. In this case you need a separate process to monitor (see my suggestion).